# Sunfounder DS18B20 disable light

Tags: led, temperature, ds18b20

I've got a problem: I have a Sunfounder DS18B20 Module for measuring the Temperature, but this Module has a little Led which i wont to turn off.
Is this possible and how?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the circuit schematic for the sensor:

[image]

If you look at how the LEDs are connected to the main sensor chip and the power rails I would speculate it is not possible to turn the LEDs off. This is certainly true for the power LED as it is connected directly to the power inputs for the circuit. As for the signal LED I suspect it would also not be possible to turn it off.

You're only option woud be to remove the LEDs and replace them with resistors of similar resistance as the LEDs. I would advise against this unless you seriously know what you are doing.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. Maybe I cover it with something :D